# Cannot ssh to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, networking

After running for a few hours, my local Raspberry Pi 3 refuses ssh connections, the green LED is lighting up sporadically:

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-13 10:01 
Nmap scan report for 
Host is up.
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

Only after rebooting the Raspberry Pi am I able to connect via `ssh` again:

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-13 10:05
Nmap scan report for 
Host is up (0.047s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

Power management on the `wlan0` interface is disabled:

```
$ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point:
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=0 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

These are the `iptables` rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -vnL
[sudo] password for root: 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  124 10420 ACCEPT     tcp  --  wlan0  *       192.168.0.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
   60  7126 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2   168 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1           
    6   702 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 13 packets, 1084 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   77  9253 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/24       tcp spt:22
    4   392 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1           
   62  6600 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   10  1038 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21,22,25,80,110,123,143,443,465,993,995
   18  1158 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 53,67
```

A few times already, I was able to reconnect after scanning all ports. But that fails sometimes.

On another occasion, I was still logged in via ssh overnight. Next morning, I logged out and, as expected, immediately afterwards wasn't able to login again.

Any hints on what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Your nmap output is a bit odd -- it's reporting the port as **filtered**, meaning "a firewall, filter, or other network obstacle is blocking the port".  If sshd just weren't running, it would say *closed*.  I doubt it is the iptables rules on the pi as they look to be a bit pointless (other than dropping outgoing ICMP packets, they don't do anything, correct me if I am wrong).  In any case, your problem is probably a firewall.

Comment: @goldilocks You mean the firewall on the client side? But how does that explain, that I can suddenly reconnect after I've rebooted the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I don't know.  I'd have a read [through this](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html), looking at the parts which describe how "filtered" is reported.  It could be that blocking outbound ICMP packets does that.  *You really should just get rid of the iptables firewall stuff on the pi side.*  What you have now is at best pointless and at worst bound to cause confusion because of the ICMP thing.

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you for the hint regarding ICMP, that sounds very much like it. I will try it out later. The Raspberry Pi is meant to be a sync server, but haven't gotten around that yet due to this problem, so the iptables isn't complete yet.

Comment: It would be a fairly simple test to disable `iptables` to see if the issue persists. If the issue "goes away", you've likely found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling logging of `iptables`, I saw that the outgoing UDP packets of `ntp` on port 123 were being denied:

```
iptables denied: IN= OUT=wlan0 [...] PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=123
```

After adding port 123 to the outgoing UDP rule

```
[...] multiport dports 53,67,123
```

the Raspberry Pi 3 no longer refuses SSH connections.